# chrome.storage.local["mykey"] is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension where I will store the password from the user in local storage. I am storing it in `popup.js` using

```
chrome.storage.local["mykey"] = "xxx";
```

When I use `chrome.storage.local["mykey"]`, I'm getting `undefined`. Can you tell me how to store and retrieve user data in a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [`chrome.storage` API](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/apps/storage.html), the correct way to store a value is with `.set`:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({"mykey": someData}, optionalCompletionCallback);
```

And to access the value later, use `.get` with a callback that accepts the data:

```
chrome.storage.local.get("mykey", function(fetchedData) {
    alert("fetched: " + fetchedData.mykey);
});
```

Comment: It works! You can also pass first argument of `chrome.storage.local.get` as `null` to fetch values of all keys

Comment: second argument is optional? Means I can use it Synchronously too?

Comment: @Volatil1 No, it means you can use it *unsafely*.  If you do not need to read the value for a long time, you might not care when it is successfully saved.